# How do I add new except page to shouldPassThrough

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-admin

I use google authenticator to add in laravel-admin

in post to new page `/auth/auth` , always be redirect to `/auth/login`, because

“/auth/auth” not in admin.auth.excepts

how do I solve this problem without edit

/vendor/composer/encore/laravel-admin/src/Middleware/Authenticate.php

I have tried to override Authenticate.php by copying `Authenticate.php` to `app/http/Middleware` but doesn't work

from

```
protected function shouldPassThrough($request)
{
$excepts = config('admin.auth.excepts', [
'auth/login',
'auth/logout',
]);
```

to

```
protected function shouldPassThrough($request)
{
$excepts = config('admin.auth.excepts', [
'auth/login',
'auth/logout',
'auth/auth'
]);
```

I want to post `/auth/login` to `/auth/auth` (with google authenticator) 
then login to laravel-admin

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add follow code in **app/config/admin.php**

```
'auth' => [

.....

// The URIs that should be excluded from authorization.

        'excepts' => [
            'auth/login',
            'auth/logout',
            'auth/auth
        ],
.....
],
```